# Failed to lookup alias 'lp': Function not implemented

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I've a server with ubuntu 16.04. Upon reboot, it warned:

```
systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
See 'systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service' for details.
systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code
```

So in the console, as root:

```
$ systemctl status systemd-modules-load 
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-08-20 16:23:47 UTC; 11min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 3328 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3328 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

And then:

```
$ journalctl _PID=3328
-- Logs begin at Fri 2016-08-19 16:14:57 UTC, end at Sat 2016-08-20 16:35:01 UTC. --
Aug 20 16:23:47 mangrove systemd-modules-load[3328]: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.6.3-x86_64-linode70/modules.dep.bin'
Aug 20 16:23:47 mangrove systemd-modules-load[3328]: Failed to lookup alias 'lp': Function not implemented
```

Function not implemented. TFW?

Comment: do you need to do parallel printing?

Comment: Nope. It's a server to host a simple web app. No printer is attached.

Comment: OK, I'm writing your answer right now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `systemd-modules-load` service reads the files in `/etc/modules-load.d` to load additional kernel modules specified here. In the directory, you will find a file called `cups-filters.conf`. This specifies modules for parallel printing including `lp`. If the modules are not found in `/lib/modules`, then the service throws that scary looking error. To remove it:

```
sudoedit /etc/modules-load.d/cups-filters.conf
```

Comment out all the lines (by placing a `#` at the start of them)

Save and exit.

Reboot.

(Note to others - there is a symlink in the directory to `/etc/modules` so that is also read - I have seen cases of obsolete modules being mysteriously specified in that file too)